# Vector of list in c++ for implementing adjacency lists

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I am trying to implement a graph using adjacency list,
using vector of lists, but the code is not compiling.

```
class Graph
{
    public:
        vector<list<int> > adj;
        int V;
        int E;

        Graph(int N);
        void addEdge(int u, int v);
};

Graph::Graph(int N)
{
    adj = new vector<list<int> >(N+1);
}

void Graph::addEdge(int u, int v)
{
    adj[u].push_back(v);
}
```

Comment: Without even stating which compiler error you get, this question cannot even be searched for for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vector<list<int> > adj;` Defines a member object of your `Graph`. You don't need to use `new` to initialize it (this isn't Java). Just call the vector c'tor in the member initializer list.

```
Graph::Graph(int N) : adj(N+1)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

C++ is not Java or C#, you don't need to use `new` to create new objects.

Instead use a *member initializer list* to *construct* the `adj` member:

```
Graph::Graph(int N)
    : adj(N + 1)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `new`, you have to assign to a pointer. I modified your code such that it now compiles fine:

```
class Graph
{
    public:
        vector<list<int> > * adj;
        int V;
        int E;

        Graph(int N);
        void addEdge(int u, int v);
};

Graph::Graph(int N)
{
    adj = new vector<list<int> >(N+1);
}

void Graph::addEdge(int u, int v)
{
    (*adj)[u].push_back(v);
}
```

**Edit**

As others have pointed out, it's better to just do:

```
class Graph
{
public:
    vector<list<int> > adj;
    int V;
    int E;

    Graph(int N) : adj(N+1) {}
    void addEdge(int u, int v);
};

void Graph::addEdge(int u, int v)
{
    adj[u].push_back(v);
}

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```